# c++ - isdigit, how to distinguish between a character and a number

Tags: c++

I want to check if my array has only numbers how can I check it out?

i try this example but this not working and i dont Understand why.

```
int main() {

char* str = new char[9];
cin >> str;




cout << isdigit(str[0])<<endl;


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

input:

1234

output: 
4

what i want is:

input: 
1234

print: ok

input:
12fg

print: not ok (because the character in my array)

I look forward to your help and explanation

thank's.

Comment: `isdigit` returns: _"Non-zero value if the character is a numeric character, zero otherwise."_  so you need to write a bit of code.

Comment: why would you expect it to print 'ok'. isdigit returns either 0 or not 0 to indicate that something is a digit

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if(isdigit(str[0]))
  cout << 'ok'
else
  cout << 'not ok'
```

extra credit 1. Using this validate the whole string

extra credit 2. Find a different way to verify the whole string (there are many)

extra credit 3. Harder, find out why you got '4' from `isdigit(str[0])`

Comment: This does not check the whole string.

Comment: @NathanOliver -- it does the same check as the code in the question.

Comment: @PeteBecker Which is wrong.  The OP is trying to find a string that only contains digits

Comment: I did not rewrite his whole program to do what he wants. I simply unblocked his current confusion. He will discover for himself that he needs to do more

Comment: wow - down votes too , its tough trying to help people :-)

Comment: @NathanOliver -- it answers the question that's as asked, which was why he got 4 and not ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
const char *s = "1234";

while (isdigit(*s)) s++;
const char *result = (*s) ? "not ok" : "ok";
```

Comment: IMHO thats way to fancy for such a beginner question. Took me a while to work out what its doing, I mean its clever but really obscures the basic logic